# FromBodyAttribute not picking up array data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a view-model that contains a list/array/collection, something like:

```
public class StackViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Comments { get; set; } 
}
```

My controller does something like:

```
public dynamic Update([FromBody]StackViewModel model) {
    ...
}
```

And lastly, in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Title);
@{for(int idx=0;idx<Model.Comments.Length;++idx) {
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Comments[idx]); } }
```

When the user edits the `Title` and `Comments`, only the `Title` makes its way to the controller. The `Comments` array is always `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you inspect the POST request in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and add to question?

Comment: you need to change your Razor view to submit the array, the genearted html should be like this :
<input type="textbox" name="Comments[0]">
<input type="textbox" name="Comments[1]">